# What is the traffic difference for ranking in various positions in search results?

Tags: seo, keywords, ranking

What is generally (some kind of average) difference between the number of website hits and its ranking in search results?

**Example:**

Let us consider the hypothetical query "example". Now, If a website that is the first choice by the web search (google like) getting **N** users per day.

How much is expected for the second choice? Third? Fourth?

1. N
2. N/x?
3. N/y?
   ...

**Maybe slightly better formulation of the question:**

What is the function between rank in web search (**for one query**) and actually outcome in visits for the ranked websites?

> daily_visits = f(rank_in_search)

I know there is a lot of other variables, but for sure there should be at least some estimation (or multiple estimations for the common cases). To narrow it down:

- expect a query with the usage of hundreds or thousands per day
- the query is something quite standard in most of the world (at least world with highspeed Internet and houses).
- the search engine is Google (or google like)

Also, feel free to add other inputs in the function I am searching for if you can answer with a complex model.

Comment: Some sites track these statistics: https://www.advancedwebranking.com/ctrstudy/ As to how accurate they are for a particular niche, you'll likely have to do the research yourself.

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is the expected click-through rate (CTR) for each ranking position - in other words, what percentage of clicks each position gets.

This can vary greatly according to the intent behind the search (commercial vs informational, for example), the device (mobile vs desktop) and many other factors but as a starting point, the desktop behavior look something like this:

`#1: 30% of clicks`

`#2: 15% of clicks`

`#3: 10% of clicks`

`#4: 6% of clicks`

`#5: 4% of clicks`

As I said, this varies greatly, especially with the increase in zero-click searches (the ones where you can see the information you want directly on the results page, with featured snippets).

I created a very simple [Organic Traffic Estimator](https://www.seowithoutbs.com/tools/google-organic-traffic-estimator) that you can play with it that might make it easier to understand: just add the monthly search volume for a specific keyword, choose a ranking and device-type and you can see how much traffic you can expect.

Not a perfect tool at all, just a nice starting point to get some ideas.